# How to make Maya show events in Wingpanel

Tags: release-freya, calendar

In gnome3 it would show evolution events in the time/date indicator. How do I get maya to do the same?

Answer (score 4):

You can enable a option to show events in the date time indicator with the following command:

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-events true`

---

*Alternatively*, you can *enable* using `dconf-editor`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Now open `dconf-editor` --> com --> canonical --> indicator --> datetime --> **show-events**

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution! Just one question: why is this not enabled by default?

Comment: Scheme com.canonical.indicator no longer appears to exist in Loki release